# cannot find symbol-method hasNext

Tags: java

I am having trouble compiling as it shows a cannot find symbol-method has next in the following line

```
 while(x.hasNext())
```

This is a program for storing data of a student in a file and displaying that data by searching for the name.

```
import java.util.*;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.io.*;

public class beta1_1
{
    private Formatter x;

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int ctr=0;
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    void main()throws IOException
    {

        System.out.println("1) Add new Information");
        System.out.println("2) View Student Information");
        System.out.println("Select Your Option");
        int op=sc.nextInt();
        if(op==1)
        {
            addInformation();
        }
        if(op==2)
        {
            viewInformation();
        }

    }

    void addInformation()throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Number of students to be entered");
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter name: ");
            String nm=br.readLine();
            nm=nm.toUpperCase();

            System.out.println("Enter class: ");
            int c=sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter section: ");
            char s=sc.next().charAt(0);
            s=Character.toUpperCase(s);

            System.out.println("Enter address: ");
            String a=br.readLine();
            a=a.toUpperCase();

            try{
                x=new Formatter("save.txt");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
            x.format("%s %s %s %s",nm,c,s,a,"/n");
            x.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue? ");
        System.out.println("Enter Y for yes or N for no");
        char d=sc.next().charAt(0);
        d=Character.toUpperCase(d);
        if (d=='N')
        {
            exit();
        }
        else
        if (d=='Y')
        {
            viewInformation();
        }
    }

    void viewInformation()throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Select method of search: ");
        System.out.println("1)By Name");
        System.out.println("2)By Class");
        int ch=sc.nextInt();
        if(ch==1)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter Name: ");
            String sh=br.readLine();
            sh=sh.toUpperCase();

            int i=0;


while(x.hasNext())
            {
                String a=x.next();
                String b=x.next();
                String c=x.next();
                String d=x.Next();

                if(a==sh)
                {
                    System.out.println("%s %s %s %s",a,b,c,d);
                    ctr++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void exit()
    {
        System.out.println("Thank You for Using");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `x`? Why do you think it has a `hasNext()` method?

Comment: The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) says that `Formatter` does not have a `hasNext()` method.  What are you trying to do with it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do this with the Formatter class, instead try using one like the Scanner:

```
    String file="save.txt";        
    Scanner sc2 = null;
    try {
        sc2 = new Scanner(new File(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
    while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
        Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(sc2.nextLine());            
        String a=sc3.next();
        String b=sc3.next();
        String c=sc3.next();
        String d=sc3.next();           

        if (a.equals(sh)){ //have to use the .equals to compare strings
            System.out.println(a+" "+b+" "+c+" "+d);
            ctr++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created x of type Formatter 
if `Formatter` is the class from java util package then it does not have any `hasNext` method and thats why you are unable to use it..

and if you are creating any class named `Formatter` and have any method `hasNext` in that ... then you can import that class in your code to use it....

`hasNext()` method is of class

```
java.util.Scanner.hasNext()
```

then you must create x of type Scanner and use `hasNext()` over it